# genymotion ADB error in ubuntu

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, genymotion

sorry for my bad language
i have genymotion in ubuntu 17.04 and android studio , in ADB tab in genymotion settings i selected root of my SDK directory , but i have error : Android Sdk not found at this location

[image]

sdk is ok and its working on android studio and genymotion is ok too. just android studio cannot run app in genymotion

Comment: It doesn't look like genymotion is okay

Comment: my genymotion device will start and its ok . the only problem is the ADB tab

Comment: Can you please show the output of running `ls` there?

Comment: i solved the problem. that was from sdk version . my genymotion varsion was up to date but my sdk version was not ...
and its now ok. thank you my friend